# Confusing analogy in the Rust Book regarding borrowing

Tags: rust, ownership

[From chapter 4.2 of the The Rust Programming Language book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#references-and-borrowing):

> When functions have references as parameters instead of the actual values, we won’t need to return the values in order to give back ownership, because we never had ownership.
>
> We call having references as function parameters borrowing. As in real life, if a person owns something, you can borrow it from them. When you’re done, you have to give it back.

Which is it now?

Not sure if this does even matter; haven't read much further - it's just that I don't know what to take away from this.

Comment: I guess what you can take away is that if you gain ownership, you'll have to explicitily return it, as in `fn foo(s: String) -> String { s }`. If you however only take a reference, meaning you borrow it, returning its ownership is done automatically and you can write `fn foo(s: &str) {}`

Comment: You can pass away objects you own (the variable/value can be used in the function, but not outside again) or you cann pass an object reference (borrowing it) to the function (the variable can be used again after the function has ended).

Comment: They're using "return" in the jargony sense and "give back" in the normal English sense. You don't need to *return* the value from the function in order to *give back* ownership to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

I think that when the book says returning the value it means that you don't need to return the value explicitly as with a mutable borrow the variable outside of the function is being edited, instead of passing ownership of the variable to the function then returning to the variable once the function is done. An example of this would be:

```
fn main() {
  let mut foo: String = String::from("Hello");
  concat_string_borrow(&mut foo); // Mutable reference to string passed as argument
  println!("{}", foo);
  // "Hello world!"
}

fn concat_string_borrow(str: &mut String) {
  str.push_str(" world!")
}
```

Compared to returning the value:

```
fn main() {
  let mut foo: String = String::from("Hello");
  foo = concat_string_return(foo); // Ownership of `foo` is given to function
  println!("{}", foo);
  // "Hello world!"
}

fn concat_string_return(mut str: String) -> String {
  str.push_str(" world!");
  return str
}
```